# query to select phone number no matter what format

Tags: mysql, replace, format

After doing a lot of searching I have only found answers on how to format a phone number being put INTO the database. But what I need is to know how to run a query that will return any phone number in any format, or at least the 3 main ones "555 555 5555", or "(555) 555-5555", and "555-555-5555."

I know I could format them going into the database but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking that if I were to enter a phone number in a search bar, with any of the above type formatting, I'd like it to return the information even if it is in a different phone number. Below is my query thus far.

```
$sql = "Select * FROM Contacts WHERE FirstName = '$Search' OR LastName = '$Search' OR 
SpouseFirstName = '$Search' OR SpouseLastName = '$Search' OR Phone = '$Search'";
```

Comment: Currently, How you store phone no in database? Is there any specific format that you follow ? or it can be in any format no restriction.

Comment: Transform the searched phone number into the unified format you store the phone numbers and your question is moot.

Comment: Not necessarily. The issue is that no matter what I do with the number coming into the database the user can still do a search in any format. If they search by entering a phone number that isn't in the format of the database they are going to get no results.

Comment: @Saurabh I'm using Varchar to store the numbers.  They can be in any format. Some may be (555) 555-5555 and some may not.

Comment: To get the results you need to get both (input search and table col val) into same format, So you need to convert input search to ex 555555 (without any `-`, `)`, `(`  ) and same for table column (you can select phone and primary key in sub query) and join that sub query to main query, apply where clause on transformed phone col. This is not suggested as it will have poor performance. So, it's suggested to migrate your all stored phone no in to unified format.